# Why does my contract deployment in Remix get stuck at "creation of contract pending"?

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

I am using Remix in Chrome.

When I click on deploy, my contract gets stuck on 'creation of contract pending'.

Can someone help me please?

[image]

Comment: Clear your cache, use `http` instead of `https` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to deploy the contract? you need the "Injected Web3" environment option to deploy to a non-local blockchain (i.e. one selected in your Metamask for example).

[image]